# Loop through an object and append the properties to an html file

Tags: javascript, for-loop, appendchild

Hi I am new to JavaScript and have been doing some practice stuff. I am struggling with looping through an Object's properties and appending each property to the DOM. Can someone provide some guidance please? I tried piecing this together through other questions but not sure where I am going wrong?

```
var person = {
    firstName: "john",
    lastName: "doe",
    age: 45,
    placeOfBirth: "somewhere"
}

for(var i = 0; i < person.length; i++) {
    if(hasOwnProperty(person[i])) {
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerHTML = person[i];
        document.body.appendChild(p)
    }
}
```

Comment: person is not array

Comment: okay, so if I enclose the object person inside of an array then this shoudl work?

Comment: it will work if you store object properties in array

Comment: but i won't suggest you to do that because it will create another for loop . time consuming

Comment: Google "loop over object properties javascript".

Comment: @mahi Object properties are already stored in an array; it is called `Object.keys(obj)`.

Comment: Unless you expect the text you are inserting to contain HTML that needs to be interpreted, it is preferable to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`. Actually, it would be preferable to create a `TextNode` and append that to the `p` element.

Comment: @torazaburo but  will it take o(n) time to search keys in object ?

Comment: @Mahi I don't see where searching is involved. Who is searching for what?

Comment: `Object.keys(obj)` returns array . so it might be doing some calculation right ?

Comment: @Mahi Don't worry about that. Although it's an internal implementation issue, `Object.keys` is most likely just returning an array of properties derived directly from the internal hash table used to represent the object. It might be O(n), but with a very small constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and you dont need `person.hasOwnProperty(key)` because key is property only . 
so it will always be true if you use `if` condition or not .

```js
var person = {
    firstName: "john",
    lastName: "doe",
    age: 45,
    placeOfBirth: "somewhere"
}

for(var key in person) {
    
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerHTML = person[key];
        document.body.appendChild(p)
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating `person` as an array. An object does not have length. Use `for in` to iterate an object properties

Try:

```
var person = {
    firstName: "john",
    lastName: "doe",
    age: 45,
    placeOfBirth: "somewhere"
}

for(key in person) {
    if(person.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerHTML = person[key];
        document.body.appendChild(p)
    }
}
```

Also note corrected usage of `hasOwnProperty()`

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/06d7kp7v/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:

```
for(var i in person){
    if(person.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.innerHTML = person[i];
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
}
```

However, because the `i in person` refers to anything within the object, we can completely remove the `if(person.hasOwnProperty(i))` because it will always have that property.

You might want to consider utilizing the Key names as well, as this will just append the value, and does nothing with the Key associated with it.

Try adding:

```
p.innerHTML = i + ': ' + person[i];
```

This should produce a "Key: value" output for each paragraph element.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. This has helped a great deal.

Is there any way that this would work with the for loop or the forEach?

From what I have seen I know there are syntax differences, not sure if there are other differences between each of these for loops?

Comment: It is possible to do person.forEach( function(i){
}
)

Comment: I highly recommend you do not use this method, because I have found that it is outdated, and there are some performance issues that have been noted as well.

Comment: You actually can only use arr.forEach() if the type is an array, not an object, so person.forEach would not work at all.